# http doesn't work from internal to access web page on dmz

Tags: http

FYI
on internal network server **app-200** http 8080
on DMZ network server **web-200** http 8080

Im trying on server **app-200** to access **http://web-200:8080** and I don't get any web page then I checked 
telnet web-200 8080 it failed to connect that explains me. it is perfect.

whereas when Im on web-200 server trying to access http://app-200:8080 and I don't get any page then I checked telnet 
telnet app-200 8080 and it is establishing connection but Im not getting web page.

Is there any way that I can track why it is not working.

Comment: Try to troubleshoot with `curl -v http://app-200:8080`

Comment: This sounds like a NAT loopback problem to me.

Comment: I found that there is an firewall that is filtering http call. all http getting dropped at the firewall.